# Plotly: How to define marker color based on category string value for a 3d scatter plot?

Tags: python, colors, plotly, plotly-python, scatter3d

I am using plotly.graph_object for 3D scatter plot. I'd like to define marker color based on category string value. The category values are A2, A3, A4. How to modify below code? Thanks

Here is what I did:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x=df_merged_pc['PC1']
y=df_merged_pc['PC2']
z=df_merged_pc['PC3']

color=df_merged_pc['AREA']

fig=go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter3d(x=x,y=y,z=z,mode='markers',
                                 marker=dict(size=12,
                                             color=df_merged_pc['AREA'],
                                             colorscale ='Viridis'))])
fig.show()
```

The error I got is:

```
ValueError: 
    Invalid element(s) received for the 'color' property of scatter3d.marker
        Invalid elements include: ['A3', 'A3', 'A3', 'A3', 'A3', 'A3', 'A3', 'A2', 'A2', 'A2']
```

Comment: I think the color specification for markers must be an array of color names or numbers. Why not specify the color name according to the data column?

Comment: Thanks r-beginners, can I specift color name using category number column like  using hue parameter in seaborn? Thanks

Comment: The format is array or list, so I don't think it's possible. If a dictionary format is possible, there is a way, but it might be easiest to add a new column to the dataframe with the color name corresponding to the category number.

Comment: Thank you r-beginnners. I will try

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I might be wrong here, but it sounds to me like you're actually asking for a widely used built-in feature of [`plotly.express`](https://plotly.com/python/3d-scatter-plots/#3d-scatter-plot-with-plotly-express) where you can assign a color to subgroups of labeled data. Take the dataset `px.data.iris` as an example with:

```
fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', z='petal_width',
              color='species')
```

Here, the colors are assigned to different species of which you have three unique values `['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica']`:

```
   sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width species  species_id
0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  setosa           1
1           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  setosa           1
2           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  setosa           1
3           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2  setosa           1
4           5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2  setosa           1
```

[image]

This example can be expanded upon by changing the color scheme like above, in which case  your color scheme can be defined by a dictionary:

```
colors = {"flower": 'green', 'not a flower': 'rgba(50,50,50,0.6)'}
```

Or you can specify a discrete color sequence with:

```
color_discrete_sequence = plotly.colors.sequential.Viridis
```

You can also add a new column like `random.choice(['flower', 'not a flower'])` to change the category you would like your colors associated with.

[image]

#### Plotly.graph_objects

If you would like to use `go.Scatter3d` instead I would  build one trace per unique subgroup, and set up the colors using `itertools.cycle` like this:

```
colors = cycle(plotly.colors.sequential.Viridis)

fig = go.Figure()
for s in dfi.species.unique():
    df = dfi[dfi.species == s]
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=df['sepal_length'], y = df['sepal_width'], z = df['petal_width'],
                               mode = 'markers',
                               name = s,
                               marker_color = next(colors)))
```

#### Complete code for plotly express

```
import plotly.express as px
import random
df = px.data.iris()
colors = {"flower": 'green', 'not a flower': 'rgba(50,50,50,0.6)'}

df['plant'] = [random.choice(['flower', 'not a flower']) for obs in range(0, len(df))]
fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', z='petal_width',
                color = 'plant',
                color_discrete_map=colors
                   )
fig.show()
```

#### Complete code for plotly graph objects

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly
from itertools import cycle

dfi = px.data.iris()
colors = cycle(plotly.colors.sequential.Viridis)

fig = go.Figure()
for s in dfi.species.unique():
    df = dfi[dfi.species == s]
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=df['sepal_length'], y = df['sepal_width'], z = df['petal_width'],
                               mode = 'markers',
                               name = s,
                               marker_color = next(colors)))
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much vestland. I appreciate you followed up my question. Yes, if I use plotly express with color_discrete_map, it works. However, if I use plotly only by using go.Figure(), it is not working. Do you know the method for regular plotly instead of plotly express? Thanks

Comment: @roudan Yes. I just included a suggestion in the original answer

Comment: Thank you vestland. yes it worked. so based on what I understand with your code, I have to use for loop and add_trace for same category points. Thanks.